# Who was the last to modify a database object?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, trace

[This](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-server-how-to-find-user-who-last.html) article describes how to run a standard report to display recent DDL changes.

If the data is captured, it's probably in a table somewhere. I would like to `Trace` this location so I can construct my own reports.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option #1

```
select * FROM sys.traces where is_default = 1 ;
```

This query contains path column. Copy the path of your trace file and now use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM fn_trace_gettable('Path Column value from sys.traces', default)
```

### Which Table(Object) is modified and Who Modified ?

```
select ObjectName, LoginName 
from ::fn_trace_gettable( 'Path Column value from sys.traces', default)
where EventClass in (46,47,164) and EventSubclass = 0  
                                and DatabaseID = db_id() ;             


select ObjectName,       
ObjectID,       
DatabaseName,       
StartTime,       
EventClass,       
EventSubClass,       
ObjectType,       
ServerName,       
LoginName,       
NTUserName,       
ApplicationName  
from ::fn_trace_gettable( 'Trace File Path', default )            
where EventClass in (46,47,164) and EventSubclass = 0  and DatabaseID = db_id();
```

---

### Option #2

**[SQL Server – Auditing Schema Changes using DDL Triggers](http://sqlandme.com/tag/schema-changes/)**

This approach will tell which column was added, or what command was used to add